# Is it possible to load a HAML view directly from the browser?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

This seems a little silly to ask but some background:

I'm a designer who just got added last minute to a rails project— I pretty much have no knowledge of rails other than what I've learned this week, and even that is REALLY slim. The literal extent to my project is in the views, so it's not like I need too much.

100% of my experience is limited to purely static html/css/js or wordpress/expression engine projects, so I don't go this deep usually.

*That said*, a lot of my front end work hasn't even been designed in the backend, so I can't access it from navigating it on the live version locally. Is there a way that I can manually load this via url?

Comment: are you developing on a live production site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
haml path/to/page.haml
```

Generates the .html file for you.